# Does casting a copy of a spell count count for "whenever you cast a spell" triggers?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Do effects that instruct me to cast a copy of a spell (e.g. [Spelltwine](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSpelltwine%5d), [Isochron Scepter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIsochron%20Scepter%5d), [Elite Arcanist](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bElite%20Arcanist%5d)) trigger "whenever you cast a spell" abilities, as found in Prowess, [Charmbreaker Devils](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCharmbreaker%20Devils%5d), etc?

I'm conscious that copying a spell on the stack (a la [Pyromancer's Goggles](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPyromancer%27s%5d%2b%5bGoggles%5d)) doesn't count as casting that spell, but I'd like to be clear on whether casting a *copy* counts.

Comment: Note: This also impacts storm counts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the effect instructs you to "cast" a spell or card, then you are casting the spell. You have to follow the instructions for casting a spell, and it triggers any "whenever you cast a spell" abilities.

[Rule 706.12](http://mtg.gamepedia.com/Copying_objects) says

> **An effect that instructs a player to cast a copy of an object (and not just copy a spell) follows the rules for casting spells**, except that the copy is created in the same zone the object is in and then cast while another spell or ability is resolving. Casting a copy of an object follows steps 601.2a–h of rule 601, “Casting Spells,” and then the copy becomes cast. Once cast, the copy is a spell on the stack, and just like any other spell it can resolve or be countered.

Comment: The actual relevant rule: *CR 111.1b Some effects allow a player to cast a copy of a card; if the player does, that copy is a spell as well. See rule 706.12.*

Comment: Thank you for the rule reference. It turns out that the rule it points to, 706.12, has more detail, so I used that instead.